# solveing Colebrook equation using Newton in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, fluid-dynamics

I make this script:

This part is for creating de variables Re and Ru so, I can replace use another. Next, create the expression so MATLAB can derivate it.

```
Re = 152788; % Reynolds
Ru = 4e-05; % roughnesss
syms x a b
dy = subs(1/sqrt(x)+2*log10((a/3.7)+2.51/(b*sqrt(x))), [a, b], [Ru,Re]);
df1 = diff(dy);
```

This is the script for Newton-Rapson, it works for other expressions.

```
f=inline(dy);
df=inline(df1);
x0=input('Enter the initial value of x; x0:  ');
precis=input('Enter the calculation precision; precis:  ');
it=0;
x=x0;
d=f(x)/df(x);
fprintf('\n %6s %7s  \n ','Iter.','x');
while abs(d)>precis
fprintf('\n %8.4f %8.4f  \n',it,x);
x1=x-d;
it=it+1;
x=x1;
d=f(x)/df(x);
end;
fprintf('\n %8.4f %8.4f  \n',it,x);
```

When I run the script the iteration never ends, go on to infinity. The friction factor obtains for the data is 0.016

Comment: Your residual is incorrect.  It should be `1/sqrt(x)+2*log10((a/3.7)+2.51/(b*sqrt(x))`.

Comment: just did the correction but the iteration ends in NAN.

Comment: What's your guess and precision?  It works just fine for me with a guess below 0.01.  In my experience, a small guess is a lot safer for naive Colebrook-White iterations since large values have near-zero slopes, which causes the Newton step to be overly large.

Comment: That was the problem, I start with 0.04 and precision 0.0001. Work fine starting in 0.03